# How to get time value in PHP with percentage

Tags: php

I want to get Remaining Time by giving it a percentage value.

Start Time: 10:07:03 AM

End Time: 5:00:00 PM

Remaining Time: 6:52:57

10% of time : 0:41:18

19% of time : 1:18:28

25% of time : 1:43:14

44% of time : 3:01:42

93% of time : 6:24:03

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide the code that you wrote attempting to perform this calculation https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can divide `end time - start time` parse to integer (this is 100%) then you get some point again divide this `point - start time` cast again to integer and check how much % from the whole summ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a good starting point:

```
<?php
$starttime = "10:07:03 AM";
$endtime = "5:00:00 PM";

$starttime_ts = strtotime($starttime);
$endtime_ts = strtotime($endtime);

echo "Start time: " . $starttime . " (Timestamp: " . $starttime_ts . ")";
echo "<br>";
echo "End time: " . $endtime . " (Timestamp: " . $endtime_ts . ")";


$v10percent = ($starttime_ts + ($endtime_ts - $starttime_ts) * 10 / 100);
$v90percent = ($starttime_ts + ($endtime_ts - $starttime_ts) * 90 / 100);
$v100percent = ($starttime_ts + ($endtime_ts - $starttime_ts) * 100 / 100);


echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "10% of time: " . date("h:i:s A", $v10percent);
echo "<br>";
echo "...";
echo "<br>";
echo "90% of time: " . date("h:i:s A", $v90percent);
echo "<br>";
echo "100% of time: " . date("h:i:s A", $v100percent);
?>
```

Basically you convert your time to [`timestamp`](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) so that you get numbers to work on. Then you can manipulate them with some basic proportions to get percentages you want.

### **Useful functions used**

- [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): Returns a timestamp on success
- [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): Returns a formatted date string

### Output

```
Start time: 10:07:03 AM (Timestamp: 1554386823)
End time: 5:00:00 PM (Timestamp: 1554411600)

10% of time: 10:48:20 AM
...
90% of time: 04:18:42 PM
100% of time: 05:00:00 PM
```

Comment: You answer is good (Very good), I will upvote you, but PLEASE, DO NOT ANSWER SUCH QUESTIONS : ))

Answer (score 0):

You should work with time stamp instead of date format, following code will help you

```
$startString = '10:07:03 AM';
$endString = '5:00:00 PM';
// convert to timistamp
$start = strtotime($startString);
$end = strtotime($endString);

$duration = $end-$start;

echo date('H:i:s',$duration);
// print 19% of duration
echo '<br />19% of duartion is: '. date('H:i:s',$duration*19/100);
```